# Want to generate unique Id's using a function in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, function, procedure

I wrote a function to generate unique id's,its working but sometimes two people are getting same id,I mean duplicates are formed. My unique id looks like 
**2016-17NLR250001**, I deal with only last four digits **0001**. I am posting my function please correct it and please help me in avoiding duplicates even though users login into same account or if they do it on same time.

MY FUNCTION:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `olmsap`$$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `fun_generate_uniqueid`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` FUNCTION `fun_generate_uniqueid`(  V_DATE DATE,V_MANDALID INT ) RETURNS VARCHAR(30) CHARSET latin1
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE MDLCODE VARCHAR(5);
SET MDLCODE = ' ';
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @CNT FROM `st_com_mandal` WHERE MANDAL_VS_MC=V_MANDALID;
SELECT dist_mandal_code INTO MDLCODE FROM `st_com_mandal` WHERE MANDAL_VS_MC=V_MANDALID;
IF @CNT>0  THEN
SET @YR=`FUN_FISCAL_YR`(V_DATE);
SELECT CONCAT(IF(DIST_SAN_CODE='GUN','GNT',DIST_SAN_CODE),IFNULL(`dist_mandal_code`,'NULL'))INTO @MANDAL 
FROM `st_com_dist` SCD INNER JOIN `st_com_mandal` STM ON STM.`mandal_dist_id`= SCD.`DIST_VC_DC` WHERE MANDAL_VS_MC=V_MANDALID;
IF MDLCODE >0 THEN
 SELECT COUNT(Soil_Sample_ID)+1 INTO @ID FROM `tt_mao_soil_sample_dtls` WHERE MANDAL_ID=V_MANDALID AND SUBSTR(UNIQUE_ID,1,7)=@YR  ;
 ELSE

SELECT COUNT(Soil_Sample_ID)+1 INTO @ID FROM `tt_mao_soil_sample_dtls` WHERE  SUBSTR(UNIQUE_ID,1,14)=CONCAT(@YR,@MANDAL)  ;
END IF ;
IF LENGTH(@ID)=1 THEN 
SET @ID=CONCAT('000',@ID);
ELSEIF LENGTH(@ID)=2 THEN 
SET @ID=CONCAT('00',@ID);
ELSEIF LENGTH(@ID)=3 THEN 
SET @ID=CONCAT('0',@ID);
ELSE
SET @ID=@ID;
END IF ;
RETURN  CONCAT(@YR,@MANDAL,@ID);
ELSE 
RETURN  'Mandal Doesnt Exists';
END IF;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not think community will be able to help you with this question. This is a complex function that requires very careful analysis of table / index access and locking. 
The only thing I can recommend is to not use existing table data to calculate next sequence as this is a bad practice.
Besides Race conditions that you are experiencing you will also get problems if the record with the last sequence is deleted.
I suggest you read this to get an idea on how to write a custom sequence generator:
http://en.latindevelopers.com/ivancp/2012/custom-auto-increment-values/

Comment: You may want to read through the 'on duplicate' insert page at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html and combine it with an auto_increment unsigned integer field